# VSCode slow to open and highlight large log files

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode slow to open and highlight large log files

I use VSCode to open large log files with the log highlighter syntax. These log files are very large, often a couple hundred megabytes. I switched from Notepad++ to VSCode for all the features. Notepad++ usually opened the files okay but lacked the highlighting benefits.

The new VSCode updates asked me to increase memory size which I quadrupled.

However some logs either take a while to highlight or never do at all.

Is there anyway to either speed this up or get this to work a bit better? Should I open a github issue?

I would really like to use VSCode for these logs but it is annoying...
Resources on PC are not an issue.

Comment: Please [open an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=bug_report.md)